# Initialize array of structs - c++

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, initialization, vivado

I am trying to initialize an array of struct in C++.

This is my struct:

```
typedef ap_fixed<16,1> ap_fixed_data_type;
typedef struct {

    ap_fixed_data_type real_part;
    ap_fixed_data_type imaginary_part;

} my_data_struct;
```

And this is my array of structs:

```
static my_data_struct IFFT_output[1024];
```

I would like to initialize my array of struct using (if possible) the same "syntax" of standard arrays, as an example:

```
int my_array[1024] = {0};
```

This will initialize my array to all 0.

What I am trying to achieve is something like:

```
static my_data_struct IFFT_output[1024]={{0,0}};
```

Where this code should initialize each field (`real_part` and `imaginary_part`) in each struct to 0.
With the above code I get this error:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of
> '__gnu_cxx::recursive_init_error'

Which seems to be caused by bad initialized static variable (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278710/terminate-called-after-thowing-an-instance-of-gnu-cxxrecursive-init)).

I know that I could initialize my data with a simple `for` loop, but I wanted to do something more "compact".

Is there a way to initialize my array of struct with the "syntax" I showed above?

Comment: My bad, typo. Fixed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like C to me. If you want to use C++ you can have:

```
using ap_fixed_data_type = ap_fixed<16,1>;
struct my_data_struct
{
    my_data_struct()
        : real_part(/*initialization code here*/)
        , imaginary_part(/*initialization code here*/)
    {
    // more initialization code here
    }
    ap_fixed_data_type real_part;
    ap_fixed_data_type imaginary_part;

};

std::vector<my_data_struct> vec(1024);
std::array<my_data_struct, 1024> array;
```

Comment: Suggestion: `my_data_struct() : real_part{0}, imaginary_part{0} {}` if `ap_fixed` doesn't have a default constructor.

Comment: The environment i am working with accept c++, I wrote the code in that way because it seemed the simplest way to do what I needed. Is there a way to initialize my array with the syntax i showed? Still a very useful answer

Comment: @MattiaSurricchio there is no performance benefit on using `static my_data_struct IFFT_output[1024];` over `std::array<my_data_struct, 1024> IFFT_output;`, you just lose safety. The absence of constructors is also error prone. If you have a C++ compiler I don't see any benefit to write C code

Comment: This code is part of a bigger one that is meant to be synthesized and run on hardware, the easier/lower - level, the better.
The static keyword is needed since it is a register which needs to be stored in memory

Comment: You can still use `static std::array<my_data_struct, 1024> IFFT_output;`  or `static my_data_struct IFFT_output[1024];` and you can check the generated code using https://godbolt.org/
Most likely the C++ code will be faster as the compiler knows more about your intent and for sure it won't be worse than the C code.

Comment: Using standard containers would also give you the benefit of compatibility with STL algorithms. Then you could use std::fill for an array of containers to the same value.

Comment: Just one last clarifying question: why did you declare a vector and then an array?

Comment: Those are just example on how to use multiple elements of type `my_data_struct`. `std::vector` uses dynamic memory allocation which is useful when you don't know the size in advance and `std::array` is basically a C style array with extra safety and features.